# Find source address from multicast message in esp8266?

Tags: ip, multicast, esp8266

I'm using non-OS SDK v2.0 for esp8266.

I join a multicast group.

I then receive a message (that was sent to multicast).

I want to respond to the sender, but in `struct espconn`, `udp.remote_ip` is the address of the multicast group, not sender.

How do I get the ip address of the sender?

Edit:
Receive function has an `void* arg` argument that is casted to `struct espconn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old method doesn't do the job anymore, but I found a way to find remote ip and port.

New code:

```
    struct espconn* udp_ch;
    remot_info  *premot =   NULL;
    udp_ch = arg;

    if  (espconn_get_connection_info(udp_ch,&premot,0) == ESPCONN_OK){
        os_printf("%d.%d.%d.%d:%d\n", premot->remote_ip[0], premot->remote_ip[1], premot->remote_ip[2], premot->remote_ip[3], premot->remote_port);
    }
    else{
        os_printf("Get info fail\n");
    }
```

This is exactly what I was searching for before. For now, as far as I can see, it works well.

OLD:

I found a way to find the ip, but I don't think it should be done this way. Until I find better, I will use this.

The first thing I did was print first 256 hex values, from `void* arg`.
I noticed that my address was occurring before a bunch of zeros.

On unicast, the starting position of 0s was 128.

I'm currently using this function:

```
uint32_t udp_get_addr(void* arg){
    uint32_t adr = 0;

    uint16_t pos;
    uint8_t* data = (uint8_t*) arg;

    //unicast?
    for(pos = 128; pos<144; pos++){
        if(data[pos] != 0){
            adr = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    //multicast
    if(adr == 1)
        pos = 172;
    else
        pos = 124;

    adr = data[pos]<<24 | data[pos+1]<<16 | data[pos+2]<<8 | data[pos+3];

    return adr;
}
```

I know this method is bad, and there is a number of things that can be changed for the better, but for now, this will do.

Edit2:

I needed the source port also. It is located 4 bytes before address. New functions that I currently use:

```
#define SRC_ADDR_U 120
#define SRC_ADDR_M 168 
uint32_t udp_src_addr(void* arg, uint8_t isMulticast){
    uint32_t res;
    uint8_t* tmp = (uint8_t*) arg;
    uint16_t pos;
    if(isMulticast) pos = SRC_ADDR_M+4;
    else pos = SRC_ADDR_U+4;

    res = (tmp[pos+3] << 24) | (tmp[pos+2] << 16) | (tmp[pos+1] << 8) | tmp[pos];
    return res;
}
uint16_t udp_src_port(void* arg, uint8_t isMulticast){
    uint32_t res;
    uint8_t* tmp = (uint8_t*) arg;
    uint16_t pos;
    if(isMulticast) pos = SRC_ADDR_M;
    else pos = SRC_ADDR_U;

    res = (tmp[pos+1] << 8) | tmp[pos];
    return res;
}
```